# The import com.google.android.vending cannot be resolved in an imported android project

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have just imported an android project and when I am trying to run it it is giving me error on the following imports

```
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;
```

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? IntelliJ IDE? Android Studio?

Comment: You need to include the market_licensing library, which is a project under <sdk>/extras/google/market_licensing/library/

Comment: Did you include the market_licensing project library?

Comment: Thanks for your help man I have not located the libraries in my sdk but I dont know how to add them...can you please help me as I am new to app development and eclipse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to review the steps [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html). It goes through the steps of adding it to your Android project, regardless of your IDE. Eclipse will work just fine.

These steps take some time and effort, but I have successfully done this before.

Comment: I have got everything setup in the project..like Google play licensing library. all the required methods and uses-permissions are defined as well but the code can not locate com.google.android.vending and thats where it is giving me the error.

Comment: I have  made a sample library project and include the license library into my project through it..and its working fine now..thanks for your advise..

Comment: Actually, I think the link you want is [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#lvl-setup)

Comment: The link provided in this answer does not give any direction whatsoever towards downloading the LVL and making it available to the project. It is just the general licensing info. The right link is given by Aharon Manne here before.

Comment: @AharonManne suggested a link which is great.. and can be found at the top of the instructions from the link I originally posted 2 years ago.. (this is an old post; why the downvote? :)

Answer (score 10):

You’re getting those errors because you didn’t import the licensing library.

Go into the folder where u downloaded the android-sdks stuff.

So there are 2 things: I) a Licensing Library and II) the Sample Licensing App

I) The licensing library is located in:

UserName/android-sdks/extras/google/play_licensing/library

II) The Sample Licensing App is located in:

UserName/android-sdks/extras/google/play_licensing/sample

OR

In Eclipse, File-> New -> Other… -> Android Sample Project -> (Choose a Target and hit next) -> Google Play Licensing Library

Step 1:

In Eclipse, Go to File-> New -> Other… -> Android Project from Existing Code -> (Locate the library, ie= UserName/android-sdks/extras/google/play_licensing/library)

Step 2:

Once you have the library imported to Eclipse, right click on the package and go to Properties -> Android. Make sure the “Is Library” option is checked.

Step 3:

In Eclipse, File-> New -> Other… -> Android Sample Project -> (Choose a Target and hit next) -> Google Play Licensing Library. My package was named “play_licensing_sample” by default.

Step 4:

Right click on “play_licensing_sample” and go to Properties-> Android -> Add… -> (Choose the Licensing Library u made in Step 2)-> Apply

You’re done!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when trying to set up my Android project for an [APK expansion file](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

The following steps resolved it for me:

- Add downloader_library to eclipse as a "project from existing source" (it has errors)
- Add licensing library to eclipse as a "project from existing source"
- Add licensing library to downloader_library project

[image: Screenshot showing working configuration]

Answer (score 4):

In android studio 2.2.3 I was able to fix the "package com.google.android.vending.licensing does not exist"
error by:

- Right click the downloader_library module from your project view
- Select "Open Module Settings"
- Select "Dependencies" Tab
- Press plus sign + then select "3 Module Dependency"
- Select "market_licensing" and press OK.

Original writeup of fix at https://kitefaster.com/2017/02/15/expansion-apk-files-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

It took me 2 days to resolve this in my project
1)I discovered the folder here

2)created a folder here

3)copied the files (less the UTIL folder) here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7sjk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio you need to add a folder same level as java(folder) called aidl. Take a look at the image for more specific.

You can get those file here - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/b8168f27f6f5b6b0ced5ef3210c0e89e8d3a5ae2/samples/MarketLicensing/src/com/android/vending/licensing

[image]